# Taking a bunch of photos with androidviewclient trouble

Tags: android, testing, androidviewclient

There is an issue, i need to automate making a photo to my android app, but there is no id for the button "take a snaphsot"

dump.py  on a screen of taking a photo only shows:

```
C:\Users\Dmitry.Markovnikov>dump.py
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/1
   android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/2
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/3
         android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/4
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/5
               android.view.View id/no_id/6
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/7
               android.view.View id/no_id/8
            android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/9
```

So how i should take a bunch of photos? Thank you!

**update**

i used dump.py -d and what i recieved on galaxy s 2 (android ver, 4.1.2):

```
C:\Users\Dmitry.Markovnikov>dump.py -d
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/1  NAF
   android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/2  NAF
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/3  NAF
         android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/4  NAF
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/5  NAF
               android.view.View id/no_id/6  NAF
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/7  NAF
               android.view.View id/no_id/8  NAF
            android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/9  NAF
```

=(

Comment: Android API version? App? AndroidViewClient version?

Comment: @dtmilano Android API level is 16, the app is using the default camera of android, androidviewclient version is 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$ dump -d
```

the *content descriptions* will also be dumped and you'll obtain something like this

```
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/1  NAF
   android.view.View id/no_id/2  NAF
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/3  NAF
         android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/4  NAF
            android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/5  NAF
               android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/6  NAF
            android.view.View id/no_id/7  NAF
               android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/8  NAF
                  android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/9  NAF
                     android.view.View id/no_id/10  NAF
                  android.view.View id/no_id/11  NAF
                  android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/12  NAF
                     android.view.View id/no_id/13  NAF
                  android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/14  NAF
                     android.view.View id/no_id/15  NAF
                     android.widget.ImageView id/no_id/16  Camera, video, or panorama selector
                     android.widget.ImageView id/no_id/17  Shutter
        ...
```

then, in your script you can do something like

```
shutter = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('''Shutter''')
shutter.touch()
```